# SQL Server : find non duplicates

Tags: sql, sql-server, unique, distinct

I have a table in SQL Server that looks like this:

```
id   filename   size
---------------------
1    abc.aaa    0
2    abc.zip    123
3    def.aaa    0
4    def.zip    124
5    ghi.zip    123
6    jkl.aaa    0
7    jkl.zip    124
8    mno.zip    234
9    pqr.aaa    0
10   pqr.zip    345
```

I need to find the rows with the unique file name "without" the extension.

So the result should be

```
id   filename   size
---------------------
4    def.zip    124
8    mno.zip    234
```

I've tried using

```
select distinct (Left(filename, LEN(filename) - 4 
from tbl
```

but that returns `abc, def, ghi, jkl` etc...

How can I get my desired result?

Comment: Why the expected result didn't contain `id = 5` row?

Comment: And why is the row with id = 4 in the results ? Because there are 'def.zip' and 'def.aaa' ?

Comment: apologies, ghi.zip and mno.zip were the unique values I was after.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `NOT EXISTS`:

```
select t.* from tablename t
where not exists (
  select 1 from tablename
  where id <> t.id 
  and left(filename, charindex('.', filename)) = left(t.filename, charindex('.', t.filename))  
)
```

or `COUNT()` window function:

```
select t.id, t.filename, t.size
from (
  select *, count(1) over (partition by left(filename, charindex('.', filename))) counter
  from tablename
) t
where t.counter = 1
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=3a0c5b1205df9ef3def9705801682bb2).
Results:

```
> id | filename | size
> -: | :------- | ---:
>  5 | ghi.zip  |  123
>  8 | mno.zip  |  234
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will give the answer to what you are looking for:

```
select id
       , filename
       , size 
from (
     select max(id) id
            , max(filename) filename 
            , max(size) size
            , Left(filename, LEN(filename) - 4) file_name
            , count(Left(filename, LEN(filename) - 4)) count_column
     from testTable 
     group by Left(filename, LEN(filename) - 4)
     having count(Left(filename, LEN(filename) - 4)) = 1) as t1;
```

Here is the [DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=aace638462e89eb81035c401b6bdece3)

Answer (score 0):

**If** the expected results are incorrect, one way would be with a CTE and `COUNT`:

```
WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT id,
           [filename],
           size,
           COUNT(id) OVER (PARTITION BY LEFT([filename],NULLIF(CHARINDEX('.',[filename]),0))) AS [Count]
    FROM YourTable)
SELECT id,
       [filename],
       size 
FROM CTE
WHERE [Count] = 1;
```

Using Forpas' sample data: [DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=3a2556755b329604d18746684aa6f26c)